# Ubuntu 18.04- it is possible to drag-drop workspaces to change their place?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher, drag-and-drop

Sometimes I have application that slide in an another workspaces, I don't know which command in particular I'm doing, but at end of the day I would replace my workspaces in the original wished positioning.

I'm wondering if it's possible to just drag and drop them to achieve that?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the order of the workspaces.

Not sure what you could be doing to inadvertently move an application to a different workspace. To change an application to another workspace, one has to either 1) use the shortcut keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> or 2) use the window menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or right-click title/header bar  or 3) drag applications to another workspace in the overview. All of these are not actions that are easily done by accident.

Comment: for the sake of future readers: hmmm I see, I have a remote keyboard above my old integrated keyboard that is died. So I assume when making my move the pressure can push the shift of my older keyboard beyond the new keyboard.